# Как использовать локальную переменную в других функциях в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как мне использовать локальную переменную из одной функции в другой так, чтобы помимо этой функции

другие не имели к ней доступа, и при этом не делая её глобальной ?

```
def emptiness():
    pass
```

Comment: Никак. Такого завихрения мозгов не предусмотрено (да и непонятно, зачем). Единственный вариант — переместить "другие" функции в другой модуль, но это, я полагаю, вам не подходит.

Comment: Объект - правильное решение. Два метода объекта будут иметь доступ к свойству объекта. Все остальные не будут видеть свойство, если оно приватное.

Comment: Вызовите вторую функцию из первой и передайте эту переменную в виде аргумента